# Get data of row when checking check button Swift OSX

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, cocoa, tableview

I made a table view with name, lastname and a check button. What I want is when someone hits that check button I want it to save the data of that checked row.

Image of tableview:

[image]

Comment: Where do you want to save the data? An alternative is a property `available` and saving all available rows when the window closes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First set tag and target for that button in cellforrowatindex like,

```
cell.btn.tag = indexPath.row
cell.btn.addTarget(self, action: "getValue:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

Then create one function to getValue,

```
@IBAction func getValue(sender : UIButton)
{
    //Here you have to set button image like selected etc 
    // Here you have to get data from your array or dictionary based on index path 
    let dicObj = self.allData.objectAtIndex(sender.tag) as NSMutableDictionary
    let firstName = dicObj.valueForKey("fname") as String
    let lastName = dicObj.valueForKey("lname") as String

    //Save records as you want it- your code here 
}

Hope this will work for you.
```

Comment: I have a checkbox I want to get the data when someone checks it. But what happens when someone unchecks it? I do want to get rid of that data that I will store in the array

Comment: Ok then you have to remove that object from your array as we did for getting value using button tag

Comment: Don't call an action `getSomething:`. Instead call it `saveData:` or `doSomething:`.

Comment: `row` isn't fixed. After sort, insert, add and delete other data is at the same row.